# shell script in android gives [: not found

Tags: android, linux, shell, sh

I have this script which works on my linux machine

```
#!/bin/sh
c=1
if [ $c == 1 ]
then
  echo c is 1
else
  echo c is 0
fi
```

But when I use this in android as follows:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
c=1
if [ $c == 1 ]
then
  echo c is 1
else
  echo c is 0
fi
```

It gives an error like:

```
[: not found
```

**EDIT**

Is there any other logic to check the value of `$c`, whether it is 1 or 0 ?

**Android shell have problem with [] in if so is there any other way to check the value of c ?**

Comment: Asides from the rest, do not use == in shell comparisons, as it’s not portable.

Comment: @mirabilos yea nice point you raised. Not portable things should be handled with extra care. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

generally `[` is an alias for `test`,

in Linux machine test is at

```
/usr/bin/test
```

and

```
if [ $c == 1 ]
```

is evaluated as

```
if test "$c" = 1
```

**BUT here in android there is no `test`**

so if with [] will not work in any case...

i will cross compile test for android and check it....!!!

Comment: Actually, `[ $c == 1 ]` is **not** equivalent to `test "$c" = 1` -- that would be `[ "$c" = 1 ]`. The unquoted version is unsafe, because `[ ]`, unlike `[[ ]]`, is not handled as special syntax by the shell, so unquoted expansions still go through string splitting and glob expansion, and the `==` is unsafe, because the POSIX standard doesn't guarantee that it will work -- only the `=` operator is guaranteed by the standard to be present and valid for string comparisons.

Answer (score 5):

andriod shell sh is actually a link to busybox, and it is invoked as

```
busybox sh
```

you need setup [ applets manually

```
busybox ln -s /your_original_sh_path/busybox [
```

if you don't know where busybox is put, try list the /system/bin/sh which you give

```
ls /system/bin/sh
busybox which busybox
```

Comment: Yes, busybox seems badly configured. A lot of symlinks have to be done in order to make '[' and others work.

Comment: android dont have /bin/busybox

Comment: sorry, I updated the post, you can find out use ls -l /system/bin/sh to see where it linked to

Comment: @Ted i am not getting your answer please can you explain in detail

Comment: /system/bin/busybox that is not found

Answer (score 2):

Android does not provide a full UNIX environment, it is not a UNIX operating system.  It has some similarities, much like how Windows also has some similarities to UNIX.  Some Android devices and ROMs try to provide more of a UNIX-like environment that others, but you cannot rely on most of the standard shell scripting tools being installed if you are thinking about cross-device compatibility.

So for example, if you look at your GNU/Linux system, you can see that `test` and `[` are actually programs.  Try this: `ls -l /usr/bin/[`.  Most Android installs do not include `test` or `[`.  That means that if you want to try to do actual programming with Android's minimal shell environment, you have to use lots of odd tricks.  You can install busybox to get a full UNIX shell environment, or you can even build busybox into your app.  I do that when I need to include shell scripts in an app (for example, [Lil' Debi](https://github.com/guardianproject/lildebi/) and [Commotion MeshTether](https://github.com/opentechinstitute/commotion-android)).

Here's an example of writing a `killall` in Android's `/system/bin/sh` environment: http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Android_Shell_tips_and_tricks You can also use the various [parameter expansions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to create some logic, you can see an example of that in the [Barnacle Wifi Tether scripts](https://github.com/szym/barnacle/blob/master/res/raw/).

Comment: Newer Android versions include mksh as /system/bin/sh which has [ as a built-in utility though, so it would work there out of the box. (Incidentally, mksh also understands “==” as an extension to the POSIX “=”.) It’s just bad luck of the original poster that his Android was not yet new enough ☹

Answer (score 1):

Use bash:

`#!/system/bin/bash`

or

`#!/system/xbin/bash`

You can check where your `sh` binary is pointing to on your Linux machine:

```
ls -l /bin/sh
```

**Edit**

BTW, use:

```
c=1
if [ $c -eq 1 ]
then
  echo c is 1
else
  echo c is 0
fi
```

Comment: android dont have bash and your EDIT also gives [: not found error. i assume the if doesnt understand [] and conditions. if i provide any command/executable binary name with if then it works as true

Answer (score 1):

Think you using the wrong arithmetic operator and there is a syntax error of a missing ";": try

```
[ $c -eq 1 ];
```

Also your location for Bash (sh) might be wrong at the top of your file:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
```

Answer (score 1):

How about checking that the .sh file doesn't contain a carriage return before line feed.

Windows \r\n -> CR LF

Unix \n -> LF

Answer (score 0):

use /system/bin/cmp for equality test.
if you need numerically test, substitute $(($c == 1)) with $c

```
#!/system/bin/sh
echo $c >/tmp/a
echo 1 >/tmp/b
if cmp /tmp/a /tmp/b
    echo c is 1
else
    echo c is 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue also and found a solution (on another site)

```
if [[ $b -gt 0]]
then
    echo 'Hooray it works'
else
    echo 'still works'
fi
```