# Any other option for if [] in shell script?

Tags: android, linux, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [shell script in android gives [: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056625/shell-script-in-android-gives-not-found)

i need to write one conditional statement in shell script.

i have used this way

```
#!/bin/sh
c=1
if [ $c == 1 ]
then
  echo c is 1
else
  echo c is 0
fi
```

this works fine in linux machine but android shell has some problem with if `[ $C == 1 ]` it gives me error like

```
[: not found
```

so is there any other condition statement in shell script so i can convert my logic at that way?

Comment: You've already asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056625/shell-script-in-android-gives-not-found). Please edit or comment on the original question.

Answer (score 1):

generally [ is an alias for test, in bash it's a built-in. `type [` to see what it's.

Another option is to use test

```
#!/bin/sh
c=1
if test "$c" = 1
then
  echo c is 1
else
  echo c is 0
fi
```

`=` for string comparison, `-eq` for numeric  comparison

Comment: android dont have test command..!!!! so its not possible now

Comment: i will cross compile test command and then i will try after that if [] should work