# ADB Receive broadcast BOOT_COMPLETE

Tags: android, adb, boot

I want to wait until the android mobile phone has started 
and the MediaScanner is done.

Afterwards I want to perform an action using adb.

adb wait-for-device will finish much before the boot sequence of the cell phone is done.

How to capture e.g. BOOT_COMPLETE Broadcast via ADB?
Something like: wait-for-boot-complete.
I don know whether this is possible?

Comment: I believe you should be able to see the BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast in logcat

Comment: how do I access that via adb programmatically within a batch?

Comment: adb logcat | grep <regex that identifies the boot complete text>

Comment: Sounds good I'll try this!
Does BOOT_COMPLETE actually also contain the MediaServer being done with his stuff?

Comment: I'm not sure, re: MediaServer. I would guess not though

Answer (score 15):

You can keep polling for `sys.boot_completed` or `dev.bootcomplete` system properties.

As for the code, I do not know what environment and/or scripting language you are using. It's pretty straightforward. First you need to find which property is being set to "1" up on boot completion by your phone's software. Let's say it is `dev.bootcomplete`. Then the following command would return control back to your script after the phone is booted up

```
adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop dev.bootcomplete) ]] ; do sleep 1; done'
```

Answer (score 4):

For those of you working in a Windows environment, this batch script works for me.

It waits until the ADB daemon is running, then begins polling the `sys.boot_completed` property and waiting for a value of 1.

It's not as elegant as a single line, but I have the script listed in my PATH environment variable so it can be called directly.

```
adb wait-for-device

:CheckAgain
set value=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed') do @set value=%%a

IF NOT "%value%" == "1" (
    timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
    goto CheckAgain
)
```

Comment: The command in my answer is being run on the device itself - so it would work the same even if run in Windows. Just replace `'` with `"`

Answer (score 0):

If your device does not have busybox installed (see [shell script in android gives [: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056625/shell-script-in-android-gives-not-found)), you can try to iterate in your computer. Something like this would work:

```
while [ `adb shell getprop dev.bootcomplete` -nq "1" ] ; do sleep 1; done
```

If your device have busybox installed, you can proceed as Alex P. commented:

```
adb shell 'while [ ""`getprop dev.bootcomplete` != "1" ] ; do sleep 1; done'
```

Of course the syntax depends on your machine (POSIX, etc).