# When to use the adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed

Tags: android, linux, shell, adb

I am calling a sequence of adb commands as below

```
"adb root"
adbd is already running as root
"adb wait-for-device"
"adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed"
1
boot_completed successful
"adb remount"
remount succeeded
"adb uninstall ..."
Success
"adb shell rm -rf ..."
"adb push ..."
9366 KB/s (46299481 bytes in 4.827s)
"adb push ..."
14 files pushed. 0 files skipped.
9701 KB/s (26658580 bytes in 2.683s)
"adb push ..."
14 files pushed. 0 files skipped.
9544 KB/s (33592272 bytes in 3.437s)
"adb reboot"
"adb wait-for-device"
"adb root"
error: protocol fault (no status)
error: protocol fault (no status)
Sleeping 2 sec. before retrying
increasing timeout by 180.0 seconds
"adb root"
error: device not found
error: device not found
Sleeping 2 sec. before retrying
increasing timeout by 270.0 seconds
"adb root"
error: device not found
error: device not found
Sleeping 2 sec. before retrying
increasing timeout by 405.0 seconds
"adb root"
error: device not found
error: device not found
```

But as you can see the android device starts throwing error of 'device not found' at last. I have come to know that "adb reboot" might be the culprit here as reboot might not have finished booting completely before next commands starts executing. To check this I have used "adb wait-for-device". But it seems that it is not able to detect device state correctly.
I also have found the use of "adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed" to rectify this error.
[Detect when Android emulator is fully booted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634041/detect-when-android-emulator-is-fully-booted)

I am not sure though when to use "adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed". Is it to be used on every reboot of the device or can I use it after every "adb wait-for-device" command ?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `getprop sys.boot_completed` *after* boot or reboot and *together* with `adb wait-for-device` like this:

```
adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 1; done; input keyevent 82'
```

When you call just single `adb wait-for-device` it doesn't guarantee that boot is completed since it only check that daemon has started properly.

Comment: It's nice to know that people still use my answer from 2012 https://stackoverflow.com/a/13095523/1778421

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find your answer and also you can see that this question differs because it is about when this command should be called, so I cannot simply provide the link.